# Building stairs in Java using asterisks

Tags: java

I am tasked with writing a program that prompts the user to input a positive number, and then it draws blocks of asterisks (*) to form stairs.  The first block’s length and width should be the number entered.  The next block should double that size, and so on until the number of blocks shown are equal to the number entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number of length and width of the first blocks and I will draw some stairs!");
        int number = keyboard.nextInt();
        for (int i =0; i<number; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<number; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Sample output for input 3:

```
3

...
...
...
......
......
......
......
......
......
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
.........
```

Comment: Could you post an example of output for several inputs?

Comment: I edited my initial post...So if I were to enter 3, it would have a length/width of 3....then I would need to double it to have a length/width of 6, and finally it stops when the amount of blocks is equal to the first number I gave. @Tunaki

Comment: @ChristianN **"The next block should double that size"** Your output doesn't double it going from 6 to 9 asterisks,

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add another loop over the size of the steps.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number of length and width of the first blocks and I will draw some stairs!");
int number = keyboard.nextInt();
for (int n = 1; n <= number; n++) { // loop over the steps
    for (int i = 0; i < n * number; i++) { // for each step, make a rectangle of length "n * number"
        for (int j = 0; j < n * number; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked!

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm uses **minimum** `for-loops` and **one conditional statement** so therefore; should work quite fine for what you want to achieve:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number of length and width of the first blocks and I will draw some stairs! ");
        int n = keyboard.nextInt();
        int count = n;
        int temp = n;

        for (int i = 1; i<=n*n*(n+1)/2; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<temp; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            count++;
                if(count%temp==0) {
                    temp = temp+n;
                    count = 0;
                }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChristianN Updated my answer, please feel free to have a look over it :)

Comment: Did you test your answer? Set `n` with `3` and see what you get.

Comment: Also `n*n*(n+1)/2;` is way more confusing than nested `for`s.

Comment: @Pshemo It's working perfectly now, just a slight change. Also, with `n*n*(n+1)/2`, it's a mathematical form I created for the number of rows needed. For example, if user enters 3, it should run for `3+6+9` = `3*(1+2+3)` = `n*(addition of first n natural nos.)` = `n*n*(n+1)/2` = **8th grade maths**.

Comment: I know that `(start+end)*N/2` is sum of arithmetic progression (which is this case is number of rows) but still `for[1..n]{ for[1..currentSize]{..}}` looks a lot clearer to me.

Comment: Look, I'm not going to argue about what's clear or what's not. I took this as a personal challenge as I initially wrote my answer that it contains **minimum for-loops** and I stood by it. The thing is it got complex reducing the number of for-loops.